# Who’s this big Marvel superhero in a blue suit?

Tags: marvel, super-hero

Please help me identify this Marvel comics character (the large blue guy in the background).  The picture is from the cover of a "Little Look and Find" kids book.  We've been googling this for a while and it's driving us nuts.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**His name is [Dr. Henry Pym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Pym), in his guise of Goliath.**

[image]

Hank Pym is a genius, one of the founding members of the Avengers, the discoverer of Pym Particles, and a modern-day superhero. He has acted under many memorable identities such as Ant-Man, Giant-Man, Goliath, Yellowjacket, the Wasp and also Earth's Scientist Supreme, as decreed recently by Eternity.

Comment: Thanks Thaddeus. I have only known him as Ant-man.  Very interesting.